# iPhone : Unable to understand the following coding

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, objective-c-blocks

I have downloaded some example coding. But I found strange coding or maybe I have seen it first time.

Can anybody help me to understand following coding?

```
NSArray *wordStrings = [response.spellingSuggestions wn_map: ^id (id obj) {
    return [obj word];
}];
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Let's break it apart, from the inside out.

```
[obj word]
```

A message with the selector `word` to the object whose pointer is in the variable `obj`.

```
return [obj word];
```

A statement returning the value returned by that message.

```
^id (id obj) {
    return [obj word];
}
```

Here things get interesting.

This is a block. Let's disassemble it:

- `^`: It's a block!
- `id`: Return type. This block returns an object pointer (`id`).
- `(id obj)`: Arguments. It takes one, which is the `obj` variable used as the receiver in the message expression. As we can guess from its name and as is made explicit here, it is also an object pointer.
- `{ … }`: The body of the block.

So, a block taking one object and returning an object.

```
[response.spellingSuggestions wn_map: ^id (id obj) {
    return [obj word];
}]
```

The block is passed to a `wn_map:` message. Let's drill back inward, at the other end of this message expression:

```
response.spellingSuggestions
```

This is actually another message expression. It sends the `spellingSuggestions` message to the object whose pointer is in the `response` variable. This sort of expression is called a property access expression, because `spellingSuggestions` should be a formal property (declared with `@property`), but ultimately it's just another Objective-C message.

Or `response` could be a structure and this expression a structure member access, but in modern Objective-C code, that's unlikely. Only you know, since you didn't show the declaration of `response`. If its type is `id` or `SomeObjectiveCClass *`, this is a message expression. If its type is something else, with or without the `struct` keyword but definitely without an `*`, then it is a structure member access expression.

Either way, this expression evaluates to an object pointer, presumably an object that somehow encapsulates or lists spelling suggestions.

```
[response.spellingSuggestions wn_map: ^id (id obj) {
    return [obj word];
}]
```

… which you then send the `wn_map:` message to, passing the block. I'd guess that the `wn_map:` method will call the block for every spelling suggestion…

```
NSArray *wordStrings = [response.spellingSuggestions wn_map: ^id (id obj) {
    return [obj word];
}];
```

… and return a pointer to an NSArray, which you initialize the `wordStrings` variable with.

---

Incidentally, another way to write this (assuming `wn_map:` does what I think it does) would have been:

```
NSArray *wordStrings = [response valueForKeyPath:@"spellingSuggestions.word"];
```

or:

```
NSArray *wordStrings = [response.spellingSuggestions valueForKey:@"word"];
```

The former will do the latter as part of its work (and the former will also use `valueForKey:` to get `response.spellingSuggestions`, rather than just sending `[response spellingSuggestions]` as the original code and the latter revision do).

Assuming `spellingSuggestions` returns an NSArray, this `valueForKey:` message to that array will do the same thing as `wn_map:` and the block: Send the `word` message to each suggestion, and gather the results into a new array—the one you assign to `wordStrings`.

Comment: Amazingly thorough answer to a fairly thin question

Answer (score 7):

This is the blocks construct for Objective-C.
What this code means, in human terms, is the following:

1. Take an array filled with objects
2. Build a new array starting from it, where each item of the new array is creating "mapping" the old item through the proposed anonymous method (i.e. all that is after the `^` character)

So, if the `response.spellingSuggestions` object is an instance of `NSArray` filled with objects which respond to the method `word`, you will obtain a new array where each object is the result of the `[obj word]` call. E.g. you can use this approach to convert a list of objects in a list of the corresponding string description.

#### Update

You can find more information about the block construct at the [Apple Developer reference page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Block.html), as stated by @Steven in his answer.

Hope this helps

Comment: Why did you put "COCOA" in all caps? It's not an acronym.

Answer (score 2):

This is the "blocks" construct. See, e.g., http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Block.html